# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error

Tags: javascript, html

```
deviceConnect.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Connect' onclick='connectSerial("+ device.id +")' />";
```

What am I doing wrong? I am breaking my head over it and I cannot see why this wouldn't work..

EDIT: device.id has a value of: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF

Comment: use, `\`this quotes\`` instead

Comment: What does `device.id` look like? What type does your `connectSerial` function take as an argument? Show us all the relevant code, please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose inner value in the double quotes

```
        deviceConnect.innerHTML = "<input type='button' value='Connect' onclick='connectSerial(\""+ device.id +"\")' />";
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If `device.id` resolves to a String then the quotes are needed.

Comment: what if  `device.id` is a number?

Comment: If it was a number then OP wouldn't get the exception. As it's written, it'd treat `device.id`'s value as a variable, not a literal.